# MySql - Lost /var/lib/mysql directory

Tags: mysql, connection, directory, logging, lost

So, the thing is that I was messing around with directories to backup and I delete the folder  /var/lib/mysql and now i cant connect to my database gettin this error (I'm using plesk panel):

**ERROR: PleskFatalException
Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: No such file or directory

0: common_func.php3:153
psaerror(string 'Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: No such file or directory')
1: auth.php3:116"**

¿Anyone knows a way to recover the files?

Comment: Restore from backup?

Comment: On the bright side, your backups will be really fast now. :-/

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: We have contacted the devs regarding your account.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's much to say here bar reach for your backups.